# PHP : How to send data as a JSON object

Tags: php, json

I have build a simple PHP API system.
Now a partner company (* that isn't quite behaving as a partner *) and they are sending us data but since their system is making a lot of requests we need to debug.

The debug data they send us are the following:
But I have no clue might sound stupid but unfortunately yes. How to send this to our system as a JSON object.

Could anyone tell me how I can send this data as a JSON object so I can see how our system responds?

```
{"requested_info":"pers_code_live","provider_id":"20","provider_group_id":"4","indoor":false,"provider_location":"buiten","StartDate":"14-10-2016 16:00","EndDate":"22-10-2016 23:30","email":null,"lang":"nl","personal_code":"wehavediscount"}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The info I receive is only readable by :

```
$JSonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

But I have no idea how to send the above mentioned data in a format that I have accept in the manner as described two lines up.

I can create a post variable with a JSON encoded array. That's no biggie. But the problem is the JSon object. I don't know how to send something as a JSon object and re-create their created situation.

Comment: In PHP, you can use `json_encode()`.

Comment: But how do I send this data as an object?

Comment: Do you mean through AJAX?

Comment: Best would be by POST if possible. Because I receive a JSOB object. Only readable by : 

        $JSonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Comment: `$ curl -d '{"requested_info": ...}' example.com/foo/bar` - `curl` on the command line is the most trivial way to do this. There are a plethora of tools that build on this with GUIs or other enhancements. Any programming language that can send a raw HTTP request will do too.

Comment: Is your question about sending data or encoding data?

Comment: My question is how to send the data to create the identical request as they are sending. Since I want to debug what they are doing. But I have absolutely no clue how to re-create this. I cannot see any errors on screen since everything is going through a remote request. And I have to use their application every time again. Consuming massive amounts of time. Which I am basically working for free for them again. Since it is sort of "support"

Comment: You did notice my above comment about [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)…?

Comment: @deceze I noticed that indeed. So directly posting it is no possibility. 

So I could use this string in whole and send it as curl? But then again I need to assign a variable? I only know how to PHP POST CURL. or am I wrong?

Comment: *"So directly posting it is no possibility"* – Wut, why? You're throwing me off here. Let's summarise: you want to emulate an HTTP request which sends a JSON body to an HTTP server; you want to emulate this request as directly as possible for debugging purposes, instead of going through some large app which will generate the request for you. This is all perfectly legitimate and sane debugging. `curl` can do raw HTTP requests for you, so that… should… answer… your question…? No? Why not?

Answer (score -1):

The standard way is with json_encode():

```
$arr = ["first key" => 1, "second key" => "two", "third => [1,2,3]];
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Which will return

```
{"first key": 1, "second key": "two", "third": {1,2,3}}
```